# Integral inequality for positive functions

Tags: integral-inequality

Is it true that $ \int_Sf(x)g(x)dx \leq \int_Sf(x)dx\int_Sg(x)dx \ \forall f(x),g(x)\geq0 $ ?

Comment: In general, no. You could try some easy examples. Why this question? Are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Look up "Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality" for a correct version...

Comment: Please consider adding some more details around your claim. A similar inequality , which goes the opposite way (but can be made to go your way with a simple tweak) is [Harris' inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality#A_special_case:_the_Harris_inequality). It is definitely not true for merely positive $f,g$.

Comment: Left hand side doesn't have to be finite if we merely assume $g,f \in L^1$ are positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $S$ to be the interval $[0,\epsilon]$, Take $f,g$ to be the functions that send $x$ to $x$. Then $$\int^{\epsilon}_0f(x)dx=\int^{\epsilon}_0xdx={\epsilon}^2/2$$

$$\int^{\epsilon}_0g(x)dx=\int^{\epsilon}_0xdx={\epsilon}^2/2$$

$$\int^{\epsilon}_0f(x)g(x)dx=\int^{\epsilon}_0x^2dx=\frac{{\epsilon}^3}{3}$$

However $\frac{{\epsilon}^3}{3}\leq {\epsilon}^2/2\times {\epsilon}^2/2$ is false for small ${\epsilon}$. It is false if $\epsilon$ equals $10^{-6}$ for example.